# Problem with solving 1st order differential equation: $3x''-4x'+x=e^{t}+e^{-t}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I do have a problem with a given task. It's about finding a general solution to the equation written in the title, but I am stuck finding the particular solution. I have already tried 10 times to solve that one, but still I can't get the answer that online calculators return.

I am using a method called "Variation of Parameters"
[image]

where:

(12) is $v_{1}*y_{1} + v_{2}*y_{2} = 0$

(13) is $v_{1}'*y_{1}' + v_{2}'*y_{2}' = (e^{t}+e^{-t}) / 3$ // in that case

That is how I tried to solve it:
[image]

So the result that I get for particular solution is: $\frac{t*e^t}{2} + \frac{e^{-t}}{8} - \frac{3e^t}{4}$

And the correct one should be: $\frac{t*e^t}{2} + \frac{e^{-t}}{8}$

So it's about $- \frac{3e^t}{4}$ that shouldn't be there. However as I wrote I have already tried to solve it so many times that I think it can't be problem with simple addition or subtraction mistake.

Comment: I think you'll find that the last term is part of the homogeneous solution, and ought to be there if you're trying to find the general solution. I note there are no initial conditions. You'd need to choose an arbitrary constant to multiply that last term.

Comment: Wolfram Dev Platform solves this DE as $$x(t)=\frac18(e^{-t}-6e^t+4te^t)+C_1 e^{t/3}+C_2e^t.$$

Comment: You are absolutely right $-\frac{3e^t}{4}$ will be included in the homogenous solution here. Thanks for pointing it out, I have spent so much time solving that task not seeing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we find the homogeneous solution. The characteristic equation is
$$3r^2-4r+1=0,$$
which factors as $(r-1)(3r-1)=0.$ Thus, the roots are $r=1, 1/3$. Hence, the homogeneous solution is
$$x_h(t)=C_1e^{t/3}+C_2e^t.$$
For a particular solution, we would normally choose $x_p(t)=A e^{t}+Be^{-t}.$ However, the $e^t$ piece is already in the homogeneous solution. Hence, using the variation of parameters procedure, we multiply by a linear factor instead:
$$x_p(t)=Ate^t+Ce^{-t}. $$
We don't need a constant factor times the $e^t$, because we know the differential operator would annihilate it.

When you plug-and-chug and solve for the coefficients, and then add the homogeneous solution back in, you find that
$$x(t)=\frac18(e^{-t}+4te^t)+C_1e^{t/3}+C_2e^t. $$

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod : You missed some signs (and closing braces). In addition, you have to normalize the ODE by dividing by the leading $3$. Then
$$Y_p(t)
=e^t\int\frac{e^{t/3}\,\frac13(e^t+e^{-t})}{\frac23e^{\frac43t}}dt 
- e^{t/3}\int\frac{e^t\,\frac13(e^t+e^{-t})}{\frac23e^{\frac43t}}dt
\\
=\frac12e^t\int (1+e^{-2t})dt - \frac12e^{t/3}\int(e^{2t/3}+e^{-4t/3})dt$$
should give the correct particular solution, with some extra terms of the homogeneous/complementary solution relative to the minimal form as in this answer.

Comment: @LutzL, My $Y_p(t)=-e^t\displaystyle\int\frac{e^(t/3)(e^t+e^(-t))}{-\frac23e^{\frac43t}}dt$ +$e^(t/3)\displaystyle\int\frac{e^t(e^t+e^(-t))}{-\frac23e^{\frac43t}}dt$ which is equal to $\frac38(e^-t+4te^t)$ combining co-efficient of $e^t$  with $C_1e^t$. Now where i am wrong, would you explain me?

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod : When you replace $x''$ in the variation computation, you have to divide first by 3, as that is the leading coefficient in front of it. So that the normalized equation reads $x''-\frac43x'+\frac13x =\frac13(e^t+e^{-t})$.